# Access violation reading caused an exception

Tags: c, pointers

> "Access violation reading caused an exception. a is 0x1300000."

I don't know how to solve this problem.
here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>

int my_strlen(char* a);
void move(char* a);

int main() {
    char a[100], temp;
    int right;
    scanf("%s", a);
    move(a);
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;

}

int my_strlen(char* a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (*a != '\0') {
        count++;
        a++;
    }
    return count;
}

void move(char* a) {
    char temp;
    int right;
    right = my_strlen(a) - 1;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *(a + right);
    *(a + right) = '\0';
    if (my_strlen(a++) >= 2) {
        move(a + 1);
    }
    *(a + right) = temp;

}
```

it seems there is something wrong with this line:

```
while (*a != '\0')
```

but I don't know why.

Comment: What is the input you provide? Is it shorter than or equal to 99 characters?

Comment: shorter than 99 characters

Comment: With `my_strlen(a++)` and `move(a + 1)` you can go beyond the string end since you increase `a` twice.

Comment: What is **move** supposed to do?

Comment: `*(a + right)` => `a[right]`

Comment: Trace through on paper and see what `move` is actually doing.

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled should have told you about the unused `temp` and `right` variables in `main`. Ensure you have warnings on. You may also wish to treat them as errors.

Comment: The ```while``` never gets to the ```null terminated character```. Try to confirm its presence at the end of your string in ```my_strlen```.